# Increasing the font size in html/css of scraped links (python code creating an html file)

Tags: python, html, css

I've scraped some links from a website, I'm then attempting to write the links
to a html file as html list items. I can't figure out how to increase the font size of the  links (and text associated with the links).

```
links =(soup.find_all('a', class_ ='link')) #get the links
with open ('testing.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write('<ul>')  #creating an list
    for link in links:
        make_list =  '<li> style="font-size:100px";>{}</li>'.format(link)
        file.write(make_list)

    file.write('</ul>')
webbrowser.open('testing.html')
```

This is resulting in something like (each link being prefaced by the style code)

```
style="font-size:100px";>
style="font-size:100px";>The most valuable brands in the world are overwhelmingly tech names...and American
style="font-size:100px";>German bonds may offer the clearest warning that the stock market痴 bull run is sputtering
```

Comment: `<li> style="font-size:100px";>` is not valid, you should write `<li style="font-size:100px";>`

Comment: @A.L semicolon goes inside the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@A.L. spotted your error.  `style="..."` is supposed to be a *property* of the `<li>` tag, like so:

```
<li style="font-size:100px;">some text here</li>
```

But instead, you put it *after* the tag opening:

```
<li> style="font-size:100px";>some text here</li>
```

So it was being interpreted as part of "some text here".